# How do make sure getData() runs before MovieCard function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, material-ui

I've been making a simple random movie generator app with react js and material ui but I've been having trouble with async functions. From what I understand, data isn't grabbed from the API fast enough to provide it to the component I made. How do I correct this? Is there a way to make sure I grab the data before showing it? Also, how do I display an image link as an image on react? Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import BTTF from "./BTTF.jpg";
import ratings from "./ratings.csv"

var movie;
var plot;

async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch(ratings);
  const movieData = await response.text();
  
  const table = movieData.split('\n').slice(1);
  const movieChoice = table[Math.floor(Math.random() * 171)];

  const columns = movieChoice.split(',');
  const id = columns[0];

  const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${id}&apikey=d3852437`;
  const poster = `http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=${id}&apikey=d3852437`;
  
  const responseAPI = await fetch(url);
  const APIData = await responseAPI.json();
  movie = APIData.Title;
  plot = APIData.Plot;

  console.log(APIData);
  
  console.log(`URL: ${url} + ${poster}\n Movie: ${movie}\n Plot: ${plot}`);

  


}

getData();


const MovieCard = () =>{

    
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        root: {
            width: 300,
        },
        media: {
            height: 435,
        },
    });

    const classes = useStyles();

    return <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="center" direction="column">
      <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image={BTTF}
          title={movie}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {getData.movie}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {plot}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <CardActions >
          <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary">Generate</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
    </Grid>
    
}

export default MovieCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

## For First Question

for async task, use useEffect hook or componentDidMount lifecycle method. In your code, there's no url called ratings

```
useEffect (() => {
async function getData(){
// setting url
const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${id}&apikey=d3852437`;
const poster = `http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=${id}&apikey=d3852437`;
try {
//fetching data from api
const {data} = await fetch(url);
const {data}= await fetch(ratings);// set your  url for "ratings" may be you tried to use "poster"
const APIData = data.Title // use response data key for storing data, it's better to use useState hook here
catch(error){
//console your error
}
}
getData(); // calling your function on mount
}, []) // empty array means no dependency. runs it on mount
```

## For Second Question

as poster is coming from response you have to check for its presence

```
{poster && <img src={poster} />}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Could you explain it further?

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood your solution but it doesn't seem to work for me. Any help would be great

Comment: @agb2k  i edited my code with comment.please check.

Answer (score 0):

In React, you use state to store the data. The idea is to have component state for storing the data you want to render from the component.

First use `useState` hook from react to make a placeholder for your data, and then use `useEffect` hook to get your data.

```
const MovieCard = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // define your async getData function here
    async function getData() {
      const response = await fetch(ratings);
      const movieData = await response.text();

      const table = movieData.split('\n').slice(1);
      const movieChoice = table[Math.floor(Math.random() * 171)];

      const columns = movieChoice.split(',');
      const id = columns[0];

      const url = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${id}&apikey=d3852437`;
      const poster = `http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=${id}&apikey=d3852437`;

      const responseAPI = await fetch(url);
      const APIData = await responseAPI.json();
      movie = APIData.Title;
      plot = APIData.Plot;

      console.log(APIData);

      console.log(`URL: ${url} + ${poster}\n Movie: ${movie}\n Plot: ${plot}`);

      // ---- set the fetched data in component state ---
      setData(/*..pass your fetched data*/);
    }

    // call the get data function here
    getData();
  }, []); // the empty array here will tell react to run this effect only once

  return (
    // ... your jsx
    // use the data variable from state to show your data like
    <p>{data}</p>
    // ... your jsx
  );
};
```